# Warning when archiving iPhone app, but still successful in upload

Tags: iphone, xcode, app-store, warnings

When I archived my iPhone application for review on the app store, I got the warning:

> Application failed codesign verification.  The signature was invalid, contains disallowed entitlements, or it was not signed with an iPhone Distribution Certificate. (-19011)

I didn't think much of it because it was only a warning. I uploaded the app to the app store through organizer and it was successful regardless of the warning. Should I worry about the warning, and will it effect the review process or distribution of the app in any way?

Comment: Usually if it submits okay, it's okay, but that's the kind of warning I'd worry about. It's not possible to definitely answer this question, but you might want to use on of your developer incidents to check on why this happened (they'll re-credit you the incident if it's an issue with Xcode / submission, otherwise they'll fully explain what the problem is and how to cure it)

Comment: Alright, I guess I'll just have to wait and see until the app is done being reviewed.

Comment: I wouldn't wait and see. Just use the developer incident. The Internet (especially SO, the Apple Dev Boards, and iOS blogs) give you practically everything you need to solve every-day issues. The incidents are perfect for extremely specific Apple issues like this. Plus, you can share the results by answering and accepting your own question, once you find out what the issue really is (whether it's something you did, and you can warn others away from it, or whether it's a bug/issue in the developer tools, and others can be on the look-out).

Comment: If I fix the error, is it possible to re-upload the binary before the review starts?

Comment: Yes, you can re-upload the binary any time. You just need to developer-reject the current binary, reset it for 'Ready for Upload' and then upload again. You can do this even during the review.

Comment: Alright, thanks a lot for your help I'll look into it and try to find the answer!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some research in the Apple developer guide and Google, I found out that I was using the wrong profile. Under Project > Build Settings > All > Code Signing > Release, the profile should be set to "iPhone Distribution: Your Name", instead of iPhone Developer.